# XDocument.Save() removes my &#xA; entities

Tags: c#, xml, entity, linq-to-xml

I wrote a tool to repair some XML files (i.e., insert some attributes/values that were missing) using C# and Linq-to-XML. The tool loads an existing XML file into an XDocument object. Then, it parses down through the node to insert the missing data. After that, it calls XDocument.Save() to save the changes out to another directory.

All of that is just fine except for one thing: any **&#xA;** entities that are in the text in the XML file are replaced with a new line character. The entity represents a new line, of course, but I need to preserve the entity in the XML because another consumer needs it in there.

Is there any way to save the modified XDocument without losing the **&#xA;** entities?

Thank you.

Comment: Are &#xA; replaced when you load the old document or when you save the new one?

Comment: @Arnold: When I save the new one.

Comment: The ideal solution would be to fix the consumer of your XML, so that it handles XML properly.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `&#xA;` entities are technically called “numeric character references” in XML, and they are resolved when the original document is loaded into the `XDocument`. This makes your issue problematic to solve, since there is no way of distinguishing resolved whitespace entities from insignificant whitespace (typically used for formatting XML documents for plain-text viewers) after the `XDocument` has been loaded. Thus, the below only applies if your document does not have any insignificant whitespace.

The `System.Xml` library allows one to preserve whitespace entities by setting the [`NewLineHandling`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwritersettings.newlinehandling.aspx) property of the `XmlWriterSettings` class to `Entitize`. However, within text nodes, this would only entitize `\r` to `&#xD;`, and not `\n` to `&#xA;`.

The easiest solution is to derive from the `XmlWriter` class and override its [`WriteString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwriter.writestring.aspx) method to manually replace the whitespace characters with their numeric character entities. The `WriteString` method also happens to be the place where .NET entitizes characters that are not permitted to appear in text nodes, such as the syntax markers `&`, `<`, and `>`, which are respectively entitized to `&amp;`, `&lt;`, and `&gt;`.

Since `XmlWriter` is abstract, we shall derive from `XmlTextWriter` in order to avoid having to implement all the abstract methods of the former class. Here is a quick-and-dirty implementation:

```
public class EntitizingXmlWriter : XmlTextWriter
{
    public EntitizingXmlWriter(TextWriter writer) :
        base(writer)
    { }

    public override void WriteString(string text)
    {
        foreach (char c in text)
        {
            switch (c)
            {
                case '\r':
                case '\n':
                case '\t':
                    base.WriteCharEntity(c);
                    break;
                default:
                    base.WriteString(c.ToString());
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If intended for use in a production environment, you’d want to do away with the `c.ToString()` part, since it’s very inefficient. You can optimize the code by batching substrings of the original `text` that do not contain any of the characters you want to entitize, and feeding them together into a single `base.WriteString` call.

A word of warning: The following naive implementation will not work, since the base `WriteString` method would replace any `&` characters with `&amp;`, thereby causing `\r` to be expanded to `&amp;#xA;`.

```
    public override void WriteString(string text)
    {
        text = text.Replace("\r", "&#xD;");
        text = text.Replace("\n", "&#xA;");
        text = text.Replace("\t", "&#x9;");
        base.WriteString(text);
    }
```

Finally, to save your `XDocument` into a destination file or stream, just use the following snippet:

```
using (var textWriter = new StreamWriter(destination))
using (var xmlWriter = new EntitizingXmlWriter(textWriter))
    document.Save(xmlWriter);
```

Hope this helps!

**Edit**: For reference, here is an optimized version of the overridden `WriteString` method:

```
public override void WriteString(string text)
{
    // The start index of the next substring containing only non-entitized characters.
    int start = 0;

    // The index of the current character being checked.
    for (int curr = 0; curr < text.Length; ++curr)
    {
        // Check whether the current character should be entitized.
        char chr = text[curr];
        if (chr == '\r' || chr == '\n' || chr == '\t')
        {
            // Write the previous substring of non-entitized characters.
            if (start < curr)
                base.WriteString(text.Substring(start, curr - start));

            // Write current character, entitized.
            base.WriteCharEntity(chr);

            // Next substring of non-entitized characters tentatively starts
            // immediately beyond current character.
            start = curr + 1;
        }
    }

    // Write the trailing substring of non-entitized characters.
    if (start < text.Length)
        base.WriteString(text.Substring(start, text.Length - start));
}
```

Comment: This is one of the most in-depth answers I've ever seen. I'm going to try this out. Even if it doesn't work (and it probably will), you get my vote. Thanks, Douglas!

Comment: You’re welcome :-) Don’t forget that the above will only work if you do not have insignificant whitespace in your source XML. If you do have insignificant whitespace, I would suggest you use the code from the other answer (below).

Answer (score 1):

If your document contains insignificant whitespace which you want to distinguish from your `&#xA;` entities, you can use the following (much simpler) solution: Convert the `&#xA;` character references temporarily to another character (that is not already present in your document), perform your XML processing, and then convert the character back in the output result. In the example below, we shall use the private character `U+E800`.

```
static string ProcessXml(string input)
{
    input = input.Replace("&#xA;", "&#xE800;");
    XDocument document = XDocument.Parse(input);
    // TODO: Perform XML processing here.
    string output = document.ToString();
    return output.Replace("\uE800", "&#xA;");
}
```

Note that, since `XDocument` resolves numeric character references to their corresponding Unicode characters, the `"&#xE800;"` entities would have been resolved to `'\uE800'` in the output.

Typically, you can safely use any codepoint from the Unicode’s “Private Use Area” (`U+E000`–`U+F8FF`). If you want to be extra safe, perform a check that the character is not already present in the document; if so, pick another character from the said range. Since you’ll only be using the character temporarily and internally, it does not matter which one you use. In the very unlikely scenario that all private use characters are already present in the document, throw an exception; however, I doubt that that will ever happen in practice.